# How to keep the input values the same after pressing the '"add to cart" button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Whenever you hit the "add to cart" button, the item adds to the shopping cart. Then the price will adjust to whatever input values you put in and will also adjust to any other item you decide to add to the cart. Well whenever an item is added, the input values will all reset to a value of '1'. Any feedback is appreciated and I am here to learn.

CODE:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>E-Commerce Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/fontawesome-free-5.3.1-web/css/all.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="p1" id="p1">
            <div class="topnavcont">
                <ul class="topleftnav">
                <a href="#p1"><li class="topnavlink">Home</li></a>
                <a href="#p2"><li class="topnavlink">Shop</li></a>
            </ul>
            <h1 class="topnavtitle">The Store</h1>
            <div class="navcartcontainer">
                <h3 class="totalnumber">0</h3>
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id="cartbtn"></i>
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="bgimg"> -->
            
            <div class="swiper-container">
                <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <!-- Slides -->
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="clark-street-mercantile-P3pI6xzovu0-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="bgimg"><div class="overlay"></div></div>

                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="michela-ampolo-7tDGb3HrITg-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="bgimg"><div class="overlay"></div></div>

                    <!-- <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                    ... -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- If we need pagination -->
                    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                
                    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
                    <div class="swiper-button-prev arrow"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-next arrow"></div>
                
                    <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
                    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
                </div>
            <div class="cartbody">
                <i class="fal fa-times" id="closeicon"></i>
                <h2 class="carttitle">Shopping Cart</h2>
                <ul class="cartitems">
                    <!-- <div><li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt1</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number"class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li></div>
                    <div><li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt2</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number"class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li></div>
                    <div><li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt3</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number"class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li></div> -->
                </ul>
                <h3 class="actualprice carttotal"id="actualprice">Total: $0</h3>
                <button class="purchasebtn" id="purchasebtn">Purchase</button>
                
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="p2" id="p2">
    <h1 class="p2title">My Shop</h1>
    <div class="itemcontainer">
<div class="item">
    <img src="anomaly-WWesmHEgXDs-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">White Shirt</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="revolt-164_6wVEHfI-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Red Shoes</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$4.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="sebastian-coman-travel-dtOTQYmTEs0-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Sunglasses</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$6.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

</div>
    <div class="itemcontainer2">
<div class="item">
    <img src="haley-phelps-RgJ-NU_qWjM-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Jeans</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$1.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="olive-tatiane-ImEzF9B91Mk-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Necklace</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$6.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="rafael-silva-fc2Q2DKBCYY-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Beanie</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$2.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

</div>

</div>


    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll/dist/smooth-scroll.polyfills.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"async></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
}
.wrapper{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.topnavcont{
    padding: 1em 0em;
    align-items: center;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) 0px 3px 6px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
.topleftnav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 10%;
    margin-left: -3%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.topleftnav li{
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.05rem;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    border-bottom: transparent solid 2px;
}
.topleftnav li:hover{
    border-bottom: black solid 2px;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.topnavtitle{
    margin-right: 2.5%;
}
.navcartcontainer{
    display: flex;
    margin-right: -1%;
    
}
.topnavcont .totalnumber{
    color: black;
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    height: fit-content;
    /* cursor: pointer; */
    font-weight: bold;
}

.topnavcont i{
    font-size: 2rem; 
    margin-left: 0.3em;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
    
}
.topnavcont i:hover{
    transform: scale(1.15);
}
.p1{
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
.p1 img{
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
.p1 .overlay::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 10vh;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.4;
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.cartbody{
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 25vw;
    top: 10%;
    left: 75%;
    z-index: 2100;
    overflow-y: auto;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) 0px 0px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30) 0px 3px 6px;
}
.carttotal{
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: rgb(22, 113, 119);
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}
.purchasebtn{
    background-color: rgb(22, 113, 119);
    margin-bottom: 5em;
    padding: 1em 2.5em;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 35%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1rem;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.purchasebtn:hover{
    background-color: rgb(11, 70, 75);
}
.cartbody i{
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    margin-left: 0.4em;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 200;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.cartbody i:hover{
    transform: scale(1.15);
}
.cartbody input{
    width: 2.2rem;
    height: auto;
}
.cartbodyactive{
    transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: scale(1);
    background-color: white;
}
.carttitle{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.cartitem{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.cartitem .itemtitle{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.cartitems{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    row-gap: 3em;
    overflow-y: auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.removebtn{
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.p2{
    height: 120vh;
    position: relative;
}
.p2title{
    color: black;
    padding-top: 2.5em;
    margin-left: 7%;
}
.p2 img{
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.itemcontainer{
    margin-top: 6em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.itemcontainer2{
    margin-top: 6em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.item{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 355px;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.atcbtn{
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: black solid 2px;
    padding: 0.8em 0.5em;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}
.atcbtn:hover{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.arrow{
    color: white;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .topnavcont{
        padding: 1em 0em;
        align-items: center;
        height: 10vh;
        width: 100vw;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) 0px 3px 6px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 5;
    }
    
    
    .topleftnav{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        width: 55%;
        margin-left: 1%;
        padding-right: 5%;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .topleftnav li{
        cursor: pointer;
        list-style: none;
        font-size: 1rem;
        transition: 0.3s ease;
        border-bottom: transparent solid 2px;
    }
    .topleftnav li:hover{
        border-bottom: black solid 2px;
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    .topnavtitle{
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        width: 80%;
    }
    .navcartcontainer{
        display: flex;
        padding-right: 5%;
        margin-left: 0%;
        
    }
    .topnavcont .totalnumber{
        color: black;
        padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        font-size: 1.25rem;
        height: fit-content;
        /* cursor: pointer; */
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .topnavcont i{
        font-size: 2rem; 
        margin-left: 0.3em;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.4s ease;
        
    }

    .cartbody{
        background-color: white;
        position: fixed;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 80vw;
        top: 10%;
        left: 20%;
        z-index: 2100;
        overflow-y: auto;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: 0.6s ease;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) 0px 0px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30) 0px 3px 6px;
    
    }
    .carttotal{
        font-size: 2rem;
        color: rgb(22, 113, 119);
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-top: 1.5em;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 3em;
    }
    .cartbody i{
        font-size: 2.2rem;
        margin-left: 0.4em;
        margin-top: 0.2em;
        color: black;
        font-weight: 200;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s ease;
    }
    .cartbody i:hover{
        transform: scale(1.15);
    }
    .cartbody input{
        width: 1.5rem;
        height: auto;
    }
    .cartbodyactive{
        transform: translateX(0%);
        transform: scale(1);
        background-color: white;
    }
    .carttitle{
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 1em;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
    }
    .cartitem{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        padding-bottom: 2em;
    }
    .cartitem .itemtitle{
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
    .cartitems{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        row-gap: 3em;
        overflow-y: auto;
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 0.5em;
    }
    
    .removebtn{
        background-color: red;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
        outline: none;
        border: none;
        padding: 0.5em 1em;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .p2{
        height: fit-content;
        padding-bottom: 20%;
        position: relative;
    }
    .p2title{
        color: black;
        padding-top: 2.5em;
        margin-left: 7%;
    }
    .p2 img{
        height: 200px;
        width: 300px;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
    .itemcontainer{
        margin-top: 6em;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .itemcontainer2{
        margin-top: 6em;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .item{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 355px;
        justify-content: space-around;
        padding-bottom: 2em;
    }
    
    .atcbtn{
        background-color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        width: 40%;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        border: black solid 2px;
        padding: 0.8em 0.5em;
        transition: 0.4s ease;
    }
    .atcbtn:hover{
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .arrow{
        color: white;
    }
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
let TotalNumber = document.querySelector(".totalnumber");
const Atc = document.getElementsByClassName("atcbtn");
const cartbtn = document.getElementById("cartbtn");
const closeicon = document.getElementById("closeicon");
const cartbody = document.querySelector(".cartbody");
const removebtn = document.getElementsByClassName("removebtn");
const carttotal = document.querySelector(".carttotal");
let price = document.querySelector(".actualprice");
let itempricestring = document.getElementsByClassName("itemprice");
let globalquantinput = document.querySelector(".qinput");

cartbtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  cartbody.classList.toggle("cartbodyactive");
});

closeicon.addEventListener("click", function () {
  cartbody.classList.remove("cartbodyactive");
});

function AddItemtoCart() {
  //INCREASING THE TOTAL NUMBER
  for (i = 0; i < Atc.length; i++) {
    let button = Atc[i];
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
      let TotalNumbervalue = TotalNumber.innerHTML;
      if (TotalNumbervalue > -1) {
        TotalNumber.innerHTML++;
      }

      //GETTING THE SHOP ELEMENTS AND APPENDING THEM TO THE CART
      let shopitem = button.parentElement;
      let shoptitle =shopitem.getElementsByClassName("item-title")[0].innerText;
      let shopprice = shopitem.getElementsByClassName("itemprice")[0].innerText;
      shoppriceall = shopitem.getElementsByClassName("itemprice").innerText;
      let cartrow = document.createElement("div");
      let cartitems = document.getElementsByClassName("cartitems")[0];
      
      let cartrowcontent = `<li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">${shoptitle}</span><span class="itemprice">${shopprice}</span><input type="number" class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li>`;
      cartrow.innerHTML = cartrowcontent;
      cartitems.append(cartrow);

      //ADJUSTING THE TOTAL
      let priceint = price.innerText;
      let pricerounded = parseFloat(priceint.replace("Total: $", ""));

      let shopprice2 = shopprice.replace("$", "");
      let shoppriceint = parseFloat(shopprice2);
      console.log(shoppriceint);
      console.log(pricerounded);

      price.innerText = "Total: $" + (shoppriceint + pricerounded).toFixed(2);

      

      //REMOVING ELEMENTS AND DECREASING NUMBER
      cartitems.lastChild
        .querySelector(".removebtn")
        .addEventListener("click", function () {
          let TotalNumbervalue = parseInt(TotalNumber.innerText);
          console.log(TotalNumbervalue);
          if (TotalNumbervalue > 0) {
            let shopremoveitem = this.parentElement.parentElement;
            let shopremoveprice =
              shopremoveitem.getElementsByClassName("itemprice")[0].innerText;
            let shopremoveprice2 = shopremoveprice.replace("$", "");
            let shopremovepriceint = parseFloat(shopremoveprice2);
            let quantin = document.querySelector(".qinput");
            let quantinval = quantin.value;
            let priceafteradded = parseFloat(
              price.innerText.replace("Total: $", ""));

            TotalNumber.innerText--;
            Math.round(shopremovepriceint);

            price.innerText ="Total: $" +
              (priceafteradded - shopremovepriceint * quantinval).toFixed(2);
          }
          this.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
          updateAmounts()
        });


      //PRICEINT1 PRICEINT2 AND PRICEINT3 ARE TO GET THE INNER TEXT OF THE PRICE IN EACH FUNCTION.

      //MAKING SURE THE INPUTS DONT GO OVER 1 AND ALSO MAKING SURE THEY WORK
      let qinput = document.getElementsByClassName("qinput");

      for (let i = 0; i < qinput.length; i++) {
        qinput[i].value = 1;
      
        function updateAmounts() {
          
          //MAKE SURE INPUT NUMBERS DONT GO BELOW 1
            if (qinput[i].value < 1) {
          qinput[i].value = 1;
          console.log('works')
          price.innerText = document.querySelector('.actualprice'.innertext);
      }
      
      
      //ADDING/UPDATING THE QUANTITIES TO THE TOTAL PRICE
          let total = 0;
          document.querySelectorAll(".qinput").forEach(function (input) {
            let qty = +input.value;
            let price = +input.closest(".cartitem").querySelector(".itemprice").innerText.replace("$", "");
            total += qty * price;

          });
          console.log(document.querySelector('.actualprice'))
          document.querySelector(".actualprice").innerHTML = `Total: $${total.toFixed(2)}`;
          
          
        }
        document.querySelectorAll(".qinput").forEach(function (input){ 
            input.addEventListener("change", () => updateAmounts())
        });
        // let carttitle = document.querySelector('.itemtitle')
        // if(shoptitle.innertext = carttitle.innertext){
        //   console.log('they are the same')
        // }
  
        

      }
      
    });
  }
}

//ALERTING USER THAT ITEMS HAVE BEEN PURCHASED
AddItemtoCart();


let purchasebtn = document.getElementById("purchasebtn");
purchasebtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  location.reload();
  alert("Your items have been purchased!");
});

//SMOOTH SCROLL
const scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]', {
  speed: 1000,
  speedAsDuration: true,
  easing: "easeinquad",
});
//SWIPER
const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  // Optional parameters
  direction: "horizontal",
  loop: true,
  speed: 300,
  // If we need pagination
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    dynamicBullets: true,
  },

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },

  // And if we need scrollbar
  scrollbar: {
    el: ".swiper-scrollbar",
  },
});
```

Comment: Create variables that correspond with your inputs outside of your click event and set them to null, then in your click event set them to the values of the inputs, then add a conditional that checks if those variables are not null `!== null` and set the values of the inputs to those variables.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the script a bit. It works now. Only when an item has already been added will the total number of items no longer be added, but the number of items will increase by one.

```js
let TotalNumber = document.querySelector(".totalnumber");
const Atc = document.getElementsByClassName("atcbtn");
const cartbody = document.querySelector(".cartbody");
let price = document.querySelector(".actualprice");

cartbtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  cartbody.classList.toggle("cartbodyactive");
});

closeicon.addEventListener("click", function() {
  cartbody.classList.remove("cartbodyactive");
});

function AddItemtoCart() {
  //INCREASING THE TOTAL NUMBER
  for (i = 0; i < Atc.length; i++) {
    let button = Atc[i];
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {


      let shopitem = button.parentElement;
      let shoptitle = shopitem.getElementsByClassName("item-title")[0].innerText;
      let shopprice = shopitem.getElementsByClassName("itemprice")[0].innerText;
      let itemtitles = document.getElementsByClassName("itemtitle");
      var isNew = false;
      let totalPriceRounded = 0;
      if (itemtitles.length > 0) {
        //update basket
        for (j = 0; j < itemtitles.length; j++) {
          if (itemtitles[j].innerText == shoptitle) {
            var quantity = parseInt(itemtitles[j].nextSibling.nextSibling.value) + 1;
            itemtitles[j].nextSibling.nextSibling.value = quantity;

            totalPriceRounded = parseFloat(price.innerText.replace("Total: $", ""));
            totalPriceRounded = totalPriceRounded + parseFloat(shopprice.replace("$", ""));
            price.innerText = "Total: $" + (totalPriceRounded).toFixed(2);

            isNew = true;
          }
        }
      }

      //add to basket
      if (!isNew) {

        shoppriceall = shopitem.getElementsByClassName("itemprice").innerText;
        let cartrow = document.createElement("li");
        let cartitems = document.getElementsByClassName("cartitems")[0];

        cartrow.classList.add("cartitem");
        let cartrowcontent = `<span class="itemtitle">${shoptitle}</span><span class="itemprice">${shopprice}</span><input type="number" class="qinput"id="qinput" value='${1}'><button class="removebtn" bid="${shoptitle.replace(" ", "")}">Remove</button>`;
        cartrow.innerHTML = cartrowcontent;
        cartitems.append(cartrow);

        let TotalNumbervalue = TotalNumber.innerHTML;
        if (TotalNumbervalue > -1) {
          TotalNumber.innerHTML++;
        }

        totalPriceRounded = parseFloat(price.innerText.replace("Total: $", ""));
        totalPriceRounded = totalPriceRounded + parseFloat(shopprice.replace("$", ""));
        price.innerText = "Total: $" + (totalPriceRounded).toFixed(2);


        let btnRemoves = document.getElementsByClassName("removebtn");
        var m = shoptitle.replace(" ", "");
        for (j = 0; j < btnRemoves.length; j++) {
          var t = btnRemoves[j].getAttribute('bid');
          if (t.localeCompare(m) == 0) {
            let removebutton = btnRemoves[j];
            removebutton.addEventListener("click", function() {
              let parent = this.parentElement;
              var quantity = parseInt(this.previousSibling.value);
              var removedPrice = this.previousSibling.previousSibling.innerText;
              totalPriceRounded = parseFloat(price.innerText.replace("Total: $", ""));
              totalPriceRounded = totalPriceRounded - parseFloat((quantity * parseFloat(removedPrice.replace("$", ""))));
              price.innerText = "Total: $" + (totalPriceRounded).toFixed(2);
              
              
              let TotalNumbervalue = TotalNumber.innerHTML;
              if (TotalNumbervalue > 0) {
                 TotalNumber.innerHTML--;
              }
              //remove row
              parent.remove();
            });
          }
        }

      }



    });
  }
}

//ALERTING USER THAT ITEMS HAVE BEEN PURCHASED
AddItemtoCart();

let purchasebtn = document.getElementById("purchasebtn");
purchasebtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  location.reload();
  alert("Your items have been purchased!");
});

//SMOOTH SCROLL
const scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]', {
  speed: 1000,
  speedAsDuration: true,
  easing: "easeinquad",
});
//SWIPER
const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  // Optional parameters
  direction: "horizontal",
  loop: true,
  speed: 300,
  // If we need pagination
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    dynamicBullets: true,
  },

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },

  // And if we need scrollbar
  scrollbar: {
    el: ".swiper-scrollbar",
  },
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.topnavcont {
  padding: 1em 0em;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) 0px 3px 6px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.topleftnav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: -3%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.topleftnav li {
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.05rem;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  border-bottom: transparent solid 2px;
}

.topleftnav li:hover {
  border-bottom: black solid 2px;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.topnavtitle {
  margin-right: 2.5%;
}

.navcartcontainer {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: -1%;
}

.topnavcont .totalnumber {
  color: black;
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  height: fit-content;
  /* cursor: pointer; */
  font-weight: bold;
}

.topnavcont i {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-left: 0.3em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.topnavcont i:hover {
  transform: scale(1.15);
}

.p1 {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.p1 img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.p1 .overlay::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.4;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.cartbody {
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 25vw;
  top: 10%;
  left: 75%;
  z-index: 2100;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) 0px 0px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30) 0px 3px 6px;
}

.carttotal {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: rgb(22, 113, 119);
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}

.purchasebtn {
  background-color: rgb(22, 113, 119);
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  padding: 1em 2.5em;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 35%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1rem;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.purchasebtn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(11, 70, 75);
}

.cartbody i {
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  margin-left: 0.4em;
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 200;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.cartbody i:hover {
  transform: scale(1.15);
}

.cartbody input {
  width: 2.2rem;
  height: auto;
}

.cartbodyactive {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: white;
}

.carttitle {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.cartitem {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.cartitem .itemtitle {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.cartitems {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 3em;
  overflow-y: auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.removebtn {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.p2 {
  height: 120vh;
  position: relative;
}

.p2title {
  color: black;
  padding-top: 2.5em;
  margin-left: 7%;
}

.p2 img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.itemcontainer {
  margin-top: 6em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.itemcontainer2 {
  margin-top: 6em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 355px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.atcbtn {
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: black solid 2px;
  padding: 0.8em 0.5em;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.atcbtn:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.arrow {
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnavcont {
    padding: 1em 0em;
    align-items: center;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) 0px 3px 6px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  .topleftnav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    width: 55%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .topleftnav li {
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    border-bottom: transparent solid 2px;
  }
  .topleftnav li:hover {
    border-bottom: black solid 2px;
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  .topnavtitle {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    width: 80%;
  }
  .navcartcontainer {
    display: flex;
    padding-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  .topnavcont .totalnumber {
    color: black;
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    height: fit-content;
    /* cursor: pointer; */
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .topnavcont i {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-left: 0.3em;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
  }
  .cartbody {
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 80vw;
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
    z-index: 2100;
    overflow-y: auto;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) 0px 0px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30) 0px 3px 6px;
  }
  .carttotal {
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: rgb(22, 113, 119);
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
  }
  .cartbody i {
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    margin-left: 0.4em;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 200;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
  }
  .cartbody i:hover {
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  .cartbody input {
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: auto;
  }
  .cartbodyactive {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: scale(1);
    background-color: white;
  }
  .carttitle {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
  }
  .cartitem {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
  }
  .cartitem .itemtitle {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  .cartitems {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    row-gap: 3em;
    overflow-y: auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
  }
  .removebtn {
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .p2 {
    height: fit-content;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
    position: relative;
  }
  .p2title {
    color: black;
    padding-top: 2.5em;
    margin-left: 7%;
  }
  .p2 img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  .itemcontainer {
    margin-top: 6em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .itemcontainer2 {
    margin-top: 6em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 355px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
  }
  .atcbtn {
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: black solid 2px;
    padding: 0.8em 0.5em;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
  }
  .atcbtn:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .arrow {
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/fontawesome-free-5.3.1-web/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="p1" id="p1">
    <div class="topnavcont">
      <ul class="topleftnav">
        <a href="#p1">
          <li class="topnavlink">Home</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#p2">
          <li class="topnavlink">Shop</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
      <h1 class="topnavtitle">The Store</h1>
      <div class="navcartcontainer">
        <h3 class="totalnumber">0</h3>
        <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id="cartbtn"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="bgimg"> -->

    <div class="swiper-container">
      <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="clark-street-mercantile-P3pI6xzovu0-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="bgimg">
          <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="michela-ampolo-7tDGb3HrITg-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="bgimg">
          <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                    ... -->
      </div>
      <!-- If we need pagination -->
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

      <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
      <div class="swiper-button-prev arrow"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next arrow"></div>

      <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
      <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cartbody">
      <i class="fal fa-times" id="closeicon"></i>
      <h2 class="carttitle">Shopping Cart</h2>
      <ul class="cartitems">
        <!-- <div><li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt1</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number"class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li></div>
                    <div><li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt2</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number"class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li></div>
                    <div><li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt3</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number"class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li></div> -->
      </ul>
      <h3 class="actualprice carttotal" id="actualprice">Total: $0</h3>
      <button class="purchasebtn" id="purchasebtn">Purchase</button>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="p2" id="p2">
    <h1 class="p2title">My Shop</h1>
    <div class="itemcontainer">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="anomaly-WWesmHEgXDs-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
        <h1 class="item-title">White Shirt</h1>
        <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
        <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
        <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="revolt-164_6wVEHfI-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
        <h1 class="item-title">Red Shoes</h1>
        <h3 class="itemprice">$4.99</h3>
        <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
        <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="sebastian-coman-travel-dtOTQYmTEs0-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
        <h1 class="item-title">Sunglasses</h1>
        <h3 class="itemprice">$6.99</h3>
        <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
        <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="itemcontainer2">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="haley-phelps-RgJ-NU_qWjM-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
        <h1 class="item-title">Jeans</h1>
        <h3 class="itemprice">$1.99</h3>
        <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
        <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="olive-tatiane-ImEzF9B91Mk-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
        <h1 class="item-title">Necklace</h1>
        <h3 class="itemprice">$6.99</h3>
        <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
        <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="rafael-silva-fc2Q2DKBCYY-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
        <h1 class="item-title">Beanie</h1>
        <h3 class="itemprice">$2.99</h3>
        <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
        <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>


</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll/dist/smooth-scroll.polyfills.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js" async></script>
```